# Eclipse RCP application upgrade to latest

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

We are currently using the eclipse 4.4.1 platform for our eclipse RCP application and want to upgrade it to the latest Eclipse platform. My question is, Is there any documented way to upgrade the same to the latest Eclipse platform or what is the documented prerequisite to upgrade the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Everything that is not covered by semantic versioning of the plug-ins/bundles and features is documented in the [**Plug-in Migration Guide**](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-03/nav/2_3) (*Help > Help Contents: Platform Plug-in Developer Guide > Plug-in Migration Guide*).

Comment: Hi Holger, 

Thanks for the reply.

Do we have to go version by version to come to the latest version?

Comment: @SandeepKumar Yes, starting from _Migrating to Eclipse 4.5 from 4.4_.

Comment: While upgrading from Eclipse 4.4.1 to 4.5,  i found plugin com.eclipse.update.core plugin missing which contributes to update sites but as per eclipse, this plugin have been removed in 4.8. How to know the exact details to know the missing plugin.

Comment: You mean _org.eclipse.update.core_. See [Git log](https://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.git/log/update/org.eclipse.update.core) and [bug 518351](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=518351) for details.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the typo.Thanks !!